# Can this filter be done with regex?

Tags: regex, filter, google-analytics

I'm trying to filter 2 sections of our website on Google Analytics using regex. The structure of the URL of the 2 sections are as follows:

1. Country pages:
   www.website.ca/about/wherewework/pages/**[countryname]**.aspx
2. Community pages:
   www.website.ca/about/WHEREWEWORK/**[communityname]**/pages/about.aspx

[Brackets] indicate placeholder, so it's different for each page.

The obvious solution is to search for uppercase "WHEREWEWORK" if I want to filter #2, unfortunately Google Analytics regex does not support case sensitivity. Is there another way to filter 1 from 2 (ie, filter all country pages) give that the entire first section of their URL overlap?

Thanks.

Comment: `Google Analytics regex does not support case sensitivity` Are you sure about this? This is pretty basic .

Comment: Just to clarify, you have `/pages` in different positions in the path. Is that correct?

Comment: Maybe you've though about this but apart from the casing the ending is different which would lead me to consider the regex character that defines the end of the match '$'. E.g. You could match #2 and not #1 with 'wherewework.*about.aspx$'.